# Angular ngx-mask prefilled data missing 0 when using suffix

Tags: angular, input, mask, suffix, ngx-mask

I have a component which display a formgroup input field. I am also using ngx-mask with the following
setup in .ts:

```
mask: string = "separator,"
thousandSeparator: string = "."
suffix: string = ",00"
```

My html component is as followed

```
<div [formgroup]='form'>
  <input
    [formControlName]="name"
    [mask]="mask"
    [thousandSeparator]="thousandSeparator"
    [suffix]="suffix">
</div>
```

The problem is when the input has value of e.g 500, it wll turn into 5,00 instead of 500,00.
Any other value e.g 999 will turn out good 999,00.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Update 1:
It seems like using the suffix=",00" is causing this problem. When using suffix=",01" the number is correct

Comment: I don't know the lib, but maybe you also need to add an attribute for the decimal separator? `,`

Comment: @Silvermind I tried that. It seems like it removes 0 even they are not trailing eg. 4040 becomes 440,00.